# Bootstrap автоматически переносится последняя колонка

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

На маленьких экранах переносится последняя колонка, на одних устройствах всё работает нужным образом, на некоторых так как показано на скрине.
Вот сама разметка:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-1 border border-dark">a</div>
                    <div class="col col-8 border border-dark">a</div>
                    <div class="col col-3 border border-dark">a</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

вы тестируете через chrome, который автоматически подгоняет разрешение под кажущееся ему правильным увеличение (94% в вашем случае).

Это иногда создает визуальные баги, которых на самом деле нет. Переключитесь на 100%.

Если проблема все же есть то она в border. Он добавляет лишние пиксели, которые, видимо, переносят ваши колонки на некоторых девайсах. (не уверен в кроссплатформенности конкретно этого нюанса в bootstrap и reboot).

Попробуйте поместить внутрь col-* ещё один div и задать border для него. Результат внешне будет тот же, что и сейчас.

```
div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-1 col_with_outline"><div class="border border-dark">a</div></div>
                    <div class="col col-8 col_with_outline"><div class="border border-dark">a</div></div>
                    <div class="col col-3 col_with_outline"><div class="border border-dark">a</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Либо используйте вместо border outline

```
.col_with_outline{ 
    outline: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Поставил 100% в хроме и убрал бордер, но на некоторых девайсах так же остался перенос(

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт и подскажите какое выставить разрешение чтобы увидеть проблему.

Comment: Запущено на локальном сервере(

Comment: В таком случае могу лишь посоветовать через "просмотр кода" в конкретно проблемных разрешениях играться с элементами и искать ошибку.

Comment: я разметку точно правильно составляю?

Comment: В grid разметке ошибок нет. Все правильно. Возможно у вас подключены какие-то дополнительные стили, которые взаимодействуют с версткой. Попробуйте их отключить и посмотреть изменится ли что-то (т.е. протестируйте вашу верстку на голом bootstrap 4).

Comment: ok, спасибо, попробую)

Comment: отключил все библиотеки и стили, кроме bootstrap, ничего не меняется, так же переносится последняя колонка если ставлю длину первой col-1, если col-2, то всё нормально(

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ в документации bootstrap, нужно было сделать длину первой колонки col-1, вторую оставить адаптивной (то есть убрать вообще фиксированное значение col-*, длина третьей колонки col-2), соответственно длина второй колонки просто подгоняется, а крайние остаются с изначальными размерами.